# Create dynamic webpage based on data from external CSV

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I have a semi-dynamic HTML webpage which displays some data (i.e. a typical stock market quote) at regular frequency of Half hour. Currently I manually create a new version of my HTML page with new data and deploy it in my server (Amazon AWS).

With this approach, User needs to manually refresh the Webpage to see updated data.

I want to make my Webpage completely dynamic with below scheme :

1. I will create a CSV file, which I will update in every half hour and deploy that CSV file in server (I do not want to depend on any standard DB to avoid additional cost)
2. My HTML page should continuously look into this CSV and automatically display new data if that CSV file is updated
3. User should be able to see new Data without any refreshing.

I have come across various web-advises however all of them suggest to update Web page based on JS code, however, data are created randomly by those JS code only - i.e. no dependency on any external data.

Can someone suggest how to achieve above scheme most dynamically?

Thanks for your time

*** My try after I received feedback from `Z-Bone` ***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    My HTML file
    </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        function getData() {
            setInterval(
                function() { 
                    var csvUrl = 'http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv';
                    // Init Ajax Object
                    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    // Set a GET request to the URL which points to your CSV file
                    ajax.open('GET', csvUrl);

                    // Set the action that will take place once the browser receives your CSV
                    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && ajax.status === 200) {
                            // Request was successful
                            var csvData = ajax.responseText;

                            // Do something with that data here


                        }
                    }

                    // Send request
                    ajax.send();

                },
                10000);
        }
    </script>

</head>


<body onload="javascript:getData()">
    <p>Current quote of Apple : 175.550</p>
    <p>Current quote of Genpact : 31.99</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it displays nothing

Question :

1. Am I moving to right direction?
2. What is need to do to change the Apple and Genpact codes based on some cell values in downloaded CSV?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd get the csv with jQuery.get, parse the content and feed it to jQuery.DataTable. You'll have to do the .get every once and a while and find a way to "acknowledge that the content has changed, something like keeping the last displayed content in a var to compare it should be enough. (Answering from the phone sorry I can't provide more information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 25/02/2018**

Here is a simple snippet that should get you going.
I really closed all ends and put a comment before almost each line of code so that you can learn from it.

My working assumption is that your CSV looks something like as follows:

```
Apple, 175.5
IBM, 155.4
MGTI, 2.24
```

Otherwise, you'll need to update the code accordingly.

I assume you'd like to achieve something a bit more sophisticated, but I just gave you the bare minumum to display what you asked for in your question. I hope this helps you understand and get to your final destination.

```js
// Change to your URL (Must have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow CORS)
var csvUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zbone3/96de8a3a836a8d93e7e9f3c3b34667b0/raw/6fdd7a6708cc07bda7fd052fe6f706ad7ac632f4/sample_csv.csv';


function handleCSVResult(csvString) {
  // Get the div element to append the data to
  var dataArea = document.querySelector('#csv_data');
  
  // Split csv to rows
  var rows = csvString.split('\n');
  
  var htmlStr = '';
  
  // Iterate over each row
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    
    // split row to cells
    var cells = row.split(',');
    
    // Extract data from cell 1 and 2 of current row
    var companyName = cells[0];
    var stockPrice = cells[1];
    
    // Add extracted CSV data to string
    htmlStr += '<p>Quote for ' + companyName + ': ' + stockPrice + '</p><br>';
  }
  
  // Set the string generated from CSV as HTML of the dedicated div
  dataArea.innerHTML = htmlStr;
}

// Init Ajax Object
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Set a GET request to the URL which points to your CSV file
ajax.open('GET', csvUrl);

// Set the action that will take place once the browser receives your CSV
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && ajax.status === 200) {
    // Request was successful
    var csvData = ajax.responseText;

    // Do something with that data here
    handleCSVResult(csvData);
  }
}

// Send request
ajax.send();
```

```html
<div id="csv_data">

<div>
```

---

AJAX is your friend.

You can use something like the following:

```
var csvUrl = 'https://yourserver.com/path/to/csvfile.csv';

// Init Ajax Object
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Set a GET request to the URL which points to your CSV file
ajax.open('GET', csvUrl);

// Set the action that will take place once the browser receives your CSV
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && ajax.status === 200) {
        // Request was successful
        var csvData = ajax.responseText;

        // Do something with that data here

    }
}

// Send request
ajax.send();
```

This way, whenever the page is refreshed, an ajax request will be sent asynchornously to the server and retrieve the most up-to-date csv file. You can take that data and display it as you wish in the page.

Furthermore, you are also able to continously check the server for updates in the CSV file, without the user refreshing the page. For example, you can use `setInterval` for this check to be performed every interval you choose. The `setInterval` would simply run the code above.

Comment: Thanks Z-Bone. I am not very familiar with AJAX, can you please help me how exactly I should use this code in my index.html file? Apologies if my question too trivial!

Comment: @Bogaso Can you please show how you currently display the data in your page?

Comment: just am sharing a miniature version of my current index file below. Currently I am updating share quote via deploying a new version of index with updated quote which I wish to make dynamic. <html>
<head>
<title>
My HTML file
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Current quote of Apple : 175.50</p>
<p>Current quote of Genpact : 31.99</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Bogaso Please also share a sample of your csv.. It will be easier this way... Give an example of a few lines

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Change to your URL (Must have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow CORS)
var csvUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zbone3/96de8a3a836a8d93e7e9f3c3b34667b0/raw/6fdd7a6708cc07bda7fd052fe6f706ad7ac632f4/sample_csv.csv';


function handleCSVResult(csvString) {
  // Get the div element to append the data to
  var dataArea = document.querySelector('#csv_data');
  
  // Split csv to rows
  var rows = csvString.split('\n');
  
  var htmlStr = '';
  
  // Iterate over each row
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    
    // split row to cells
    var cells = row.split(',');
    
    // Extract data from cell 1 and 2 of current row
    var companyName = cells[0];
    var stockPrice = cells[1];
    
    // Add extracted CSV data to string
    htmlStr += '<p>Quote for ' + companyName + ': ' + stockPrice + '</p><br>';
  }
  
  // Set the string generated from CSV as HTML of the dedicated div
  dataArea.innerHTML = htmlStr;
}

// Init Ajax Object
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Set a GET request to the URL which points to your CSV file
ajax.open('GET', csvUrl);

// Set the action that will take place once the browser receives your CSV
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && ajax.status === 200) {
    // Request was successful
    var csvData = ajax.responseText;

    // Do something with that data here
    handleCSVResult(csvData);
  }
}

// Send request
ajax.send();
```

```html
<div id="csv_data">

<div>
```